# Ionic 2: use NavController

Tags: javascript, ionic2

I'm trying to import NavController in a constructor from a class, following the docs/examples:

```
import {NavController} from "ionic-framework/ionic";
//some other code
export class SignUp {
    constructor(nav: NavController) {
        this.nav = nav;
    }
}
```

and the console outputs:
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./pages/signup/signup"

if I remove the constructor, there's no error.

It seems there's some sort of error in the construct() but I can't find out, I have seen differents examples and the piece of code I wrote is the same from them.
Any idea?

EDIT: on the CLI I saw this error:

```
ERROR in ./app/pages/signup/signup.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: app/pages/signup/signup.js: Unexpected token (10:16)
   8 | export class SignUp {
   9 | 
> 10 |  constructor(nav: NavController) {
     |                 ^
  11 |      this.nav = NavController;
  12 |      console.log(this.nav)
  13 |  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    export class Signup {
        static get parameters() {
            return [[NavController]];
        }
        constructor(nav) {
            this.nav = nav;
            ... 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect way. Worked like a charm :)

Comment: And how to add two parameter into this ? Like I want NavController, FormBuilder together.

Comment: return [[NavController],[FormBuilder]];
}
constructor(nav, formbuilder) {
this.nav = nav;
this.formbuilder = formbuilder;
}

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong. You should have `this.nav = nav`  in the constructor, or just put `public` before nav in the parameters like:

```
constructor(public nav: NavController) {

    }
```

and you wont ne

Comment: Tried with `public nav: NavController` , but showing same error.